# Allow users to edit only their enities in sonata

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to allow some users to add news, but also I don't want them to edit each others newses. So **after loggin to admin panel they should be able to see only theirs newses**. I'm currently doing this with sonata.

Is there any configuration for this?

My service.yml:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.news:
        class: MyBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "News" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundle\Entity\News
            - ~
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundle]]
```

NewsAdmin contains regular stuff so there is no point in putting it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the security context service into your NewsAdmin

```
class NewsAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $security;
    protected $em;

    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, $entityManager, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function getNewInstance()
    {
        $news = parent::getNewInstance();
        $news->setUser($this->security->getToken()->getUser());

        return $formDefinition;
    }

    public function createQuery($context = 'list')
    {
        $queryBuilder = $this->getModelManager()->getEntityManager($this->getClass())->createQueryBuilder();

        $queryBuilder
            ->select('news')
            ->from($this->getClass(), 'news')
            ->andWhere('news.user = :user')
            ->setParameter(':user', $this->security->getToken()->getUser());

        $proxyQuery = new ProxyQuery($queryBuilder);
        return $proxyQuery;
    }
```

And in your Admin definition:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.news:
        class: MyBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "News" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - MyBundle\Entity\News
            - ~
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@security.context"
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [MyBundle]]
```